# How to tag releases to Git using Capistrano v3

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, tags, capistrano3

I'm working with Capistrano v3 and I'm trying to tag deployments and push them to github.

So far I have:

```
task :tag do 
    on roles (:app) do
      puts "\x1B[35m Tagging deployment... \x1B[0m"

      timestamp = Time.now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
      tag_name = "#{fetch(:stage)}_#{timestamp}"
      puts "\x1B[35m tag name... \x1B[0m" + tag_name
      execute "cd #{repo_path} && git tag #{tag_name} && git push origin --tags"

      puts "\x1B[35m Done. Deployment tagged as #{fetch(:tag_name)} \x1B[0m"
    end
  end
```

The thing is `repo_path` is a mirrored repo and of course I cannot perform or use `--tags` because it will raise an error.

Any ideas on how to do this very simple task?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

I basically did the following:

```
desc "Tag deployed release"
    task :tag do
    run_locally do
      timestamp = Time.now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
      tag_name = "#{fetch(:stage)}_#{timestamp}"
      latest_revision = fetch(:current_revision)
      strategy.git "tag -f #{tag_name} #{latest_revision}"
      strategy.git "push -f --tags"
      info "[cap-deploy-tagger] Tagged #{latest_revision} with #{tag_name}"
    end
  end

after :cleanup, 'deploy:tag'
```

which makes full sense. I'm tagging the deployment locally instead of doing it directly on the server :)